# Google Analytics Exclude URI filtering

Tags: google-analytics, regex

I have a tracking code which is currently used on two ORACLE APEX webapplications. (210 and 400).

I have made a view in Google Analytics, which contains a filter that should exclude the 400 application from the view (see img below).

[image]

I tested the regex at https://regex-golang.appspot.com/assets/html/index.html
[image]

Which should exclude tracking in the view from the following url:

```
https://[mydomain]/pls/apex/f?p=400:2000:115045610891166:
```

And should allow the following url to be tracked in the view:

```
https://[mydomain]/pls/apex/f?p=210:1000:398513556605:
```

However, in Google Analytics I still see the tracking:

[image]

Hopefully someone can tell me whats wrong with my regex.

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression looks fine. That screenshot, however, looks like it is from your real-time reports. Real-time reports do not always respect filters, especially if those filters were recently created.

The safer option is to allow data to collect for 12-24 hours and then inspect your content reports for the day. You should hopefully see the absence of any pages with "400:" in the URL.